# Why does my 3D model not translate the way I expect?

Tags: xna, c#, camera, models

In my first image, my model displays correctly:

[image]

But when I move the model's position along the Z-axis (forward) I get this, yet the Y-axis doesnt change. An if I keep going, the model disappears into the ground:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how I can get the model to translate properly visually? Here is how Im calling the model and the terrain in `draw()`:

```
cameraPosition = new Vector3(camX, camY, camZ);

        // Copy any parent transforms.
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[mShockwave.Bones.Count];
        mShockwave.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);
        Matrix[] ttransforms = new Matrix[terrain.Bones.Count];
        terrain.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(ttransforms);

        // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in mShockwave.Meshes)
        {
            // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
            // as our camera and projection.
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                // Looking at the model (picture shouldnt change other than rotation)
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, 
                    modelPosition, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                    1.0f, 10000.0f);
                effect.TextureEnabled = true;
            }

            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            prepare3d();
            mesh.Draw();
        }

        //Terrain test
        foreach (ModelMesh meshT in terrain.Meshes)
        {

            foreach (BasicEffect effect in meshT.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
                effect.World = ttransforms[meshT.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(0)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(terrainPosition);
                // Looking at the model (picture shouldnt change other than rotation)
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                    terrainPosition, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                    1.0f, 10000.0f);
                effect.TextureEnabled = true;
            }

            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            prepare3d();
            meshT.Draw();
            DrawText();
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I'm suspecting that there may be something wrong with how I'm handling my camera. The model rotates fine on its Y-axis.

Comment: Why should Y axis of model's position change if you move your model along Z axis?

Comment: snake5 I think that's the entire point of the question. Visually it looks like the Y-Axis is changing, but he isn't changing it :).

Comment: Oh, I've got it now. Both Z and Y are changing, even though only Z is supposed to change, right? OP has some confusing wording there. In that case, I'd suggest stepping through the code with a debugger and look at the values. I'm also afraid there's too little information for us to find answers.

Comment: Forgive the "stupid human trick" questions, but... Are you sure the Z axis is forward? How are you getting the values for the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an bug in my camera. I was translating in `Vector3.Up` and `Vector3.Right` at the same time within my input class. Both were set to one thumbstick. Removing `Vector3.Right` from the thumbstick for movement in the cardinal directions resolved the problem.